# How to have correct paths for SASS imports for NPM packages with v3 (flat dir structure)

Tags: npm

I have a custom NPM module which requires other SASS based NPM modules eg Breakpoint SASS and Susy.

In my modules package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "breakpoint-sass": "^2.7.0",
  "susy": "^2.2.12"
}
```

When I was using NPM v2 the dependnacies were nested. So in my module's SASS file I could just include the dependancies with this:

```
@import './node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/breakpoint';
@import './node_modules/susy/sass/susy';
```

However as of NPM v3 dependancies are now installed as a flat structure.

In my projct root:

```
node_modules/custom
node_modules/breakpoint-sass
node_modules/susy
```

As I'm using Gulp SASS Ive got this working in 1 project using includePaths. However as a custom build task is required my module is essentially broken. Is there a solution to this?

I considered using a naked node-sass implementation within the module which would use includePaths, but this seems like a lot of work just to resolve a path.

A separate but possibly related issue is that I have fonts in my custom module which Im importing with @font-face in my custom module's SASS file. When I import my module's SASS file into my main project's SASS file then the @font-face paths are wrong.

Comment: Kindly tell me your error log so it easily for me to resolved this issue because this error resolved by me in past. How you run this and also mention your folder structure.